# TFS Fakes Build Unit test failure

Tags: c#, tfsbuild

We have a VS2013 .net 5.0 Solution (VS2013 Premium) with all Unit tests passing fine locally but failing several tests when running in VS Test Loader by TFS Build with this or similar Exception: `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Fakes.ShimEventLog' from assembly 'System.4.0.0.0.Fakes, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703'.`
This is an example of a failing test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WriteToEventLogTest_HappyPath()
    {
        EventLogEntryType eTypeInfo = EventLogEntryType.Information;
        bool sourceExistCalled = false;
        bool writeEntrycalled = false;

        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            ShimEventLog.SourceExistsString = s =>
            {
                sourceExistCalled = true;
                return true;
            };

            ShimEventLog.AllInstances.WriteEntryStringEventLogEntryType = (@this, str, et) =>
            {
                writeEntrycalled = true;
            };

            Logging.WriteToEventLog(IpAddress, eTypeInfo);
            Assert.IsTrue(sourceExistCalled, "SourceExist() not called");
            Assert.IsTrue(writeEntrycalled, "WriteEntry() not called");
        }
    }`
```

We using TFS 2013 update 5 running on Windows Server 2012 R2. Is there anything that can likely cause this problem? Should we update TFS to the latest which is Update 5 at the moment?

Comment: Is the assembly there on the TFS machine, either in the local workspace directory (I'm not familiar with TFS) or the GAC?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Assembly is on a Build Agent machine, but doesn't go to the GAC

Comment: Try enabling fusion logging. It goes without saying, but did you double-check that the DLL is in the expected/right location, and that the version, culture, and public key token all match exactly?

Comment: Yes, assembly is in specified location, version matches, but TFS fails the Build on failing the test so no Output.

Comment: what kind of unit test you created.automapper test or something else

Comment: Something else. Those are not Automapper tests, we use it to Fake e-mail message objects to test e-mail functionality.

Comment: Maybe show the code for the tests, as well as the setup of the shim.  Do other shims work by not this one?  Do you need a specific version of VS in order to get access to Fakes?  If so, is the right version installed on the build machine?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated. Yes, other shims are working except several that are in one particular project. AFAIK Shims require VS2013 Professional/Ultimate and we using Professional on both Developer and Build machine.

Comment: If you have VS Professional on the build machine then what happens when you RDP and open the solution there and try to run all your tests from Visual Studio?

Comment: We actually have VS Premium Update 5, my mistake

Comment: @dustinmoris If you RDP and run it from Build Machine all tests are passing

Comment: @Victor, I can make it work via adding the FakesAssemblies folder (which contains these fake assemblies) into TFS version control. Could you please have a try?

Comment: It doesn't make sense why it fails from the TFS build yet. I would suggest to slowly work yourself up to eliminate the root causes. So far you know that you have the right assemblies in the right place, it works from Visual Studio on the build machine, but not from the TFS triggered build and it fails for only a small set of tests and they fail to actually build the project, correct? Could you try next to build your test project from the command line? See here for a refenrece: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Comment: Maybe your TFS build uses a different MSBuild version or has a permission issue to access the assemblies.

Comment: @Vicky yes, we tried that and now it's failing a couple of different tests from a different test project.

Comment: @dustinmorris I agree that it doesn't make sense. If it did I probably wouldn't even post the original question. Tests just randomly fail when running by VS Test Runner by TFS Build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was resolved by sharing fakes configuration files between the Test projects on a Solution level

Comment: Can you please provide more information on how would you do that?

Comment: @zaitsman Sure, we created a new project where we consolidated all the Fakes throughout Solution and then linked them in various Test projects. That resolved all the Build issues for us.

Comment: @Victor linked or added a reference could you give a touch more detail ? thx

Answer (score 0):

In our situation, we were running several unit test DLLs through VSTest in Jenkins.

Example call:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" 
"./TestDLL1.UnitTests/bin/Debug/TestDLL1.UnitTests.dll" 
"./TestDLL2.UnitTests/bin/Debug/TestDLL2.UnitTests.dll" 
"./TestDLL3.UnitTests/bin/Debug/TestDLL3.UnitTests.dll" 
/Enablecodecoverage /UseVsixExtensions:false /Logger:trx
```

Some of the test projects had Fakes for the same DLL, with most setup to Fake everything. One test project was only faking one class, as the XML shows below, in order to prevent the warning about "Some fakes could not be generated."

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="Utilities"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear />
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear />
    <Add FullName="UIUtils.ExceptionDisplay"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

For some reason, VSTest was using the above version for the other test projects. Modifying the one test project to generate all the fakes fixed the issue with System.TypeLoadException. We may consolidate our Fakes in the future, to be able to more easily limit which classes are faked, but for now this was a much quicker solution to the issue.

If only there was an easier way to suppress the "Some fakes could not be generated" warning...

Answer (score 0):

just has a similar issue when using Shims in multiple separate Unit test projects. Apparently the generated shims can overwrite each over or something like that.

Here's the instructions I followed to fix it: Scroll to the middle of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx

It's under the heading of optimise build times, but use it to fix your problem too.

Because such assemblies rarely change on your machine, you can reuse the generated Fakes assemblies in other projects. From your unit test projects, you can simply take a reference to the
   compiled Fakes assemblies that are placed under the FakesAssemblies
   in the project folder.

- Create a new Class Library with the .NET runtime version matching
  your test projects. Let’s call it Fakes.Prebuild. Remove the
  class1.cs file from the project, not needed.

  Add reference to all the System and third-party assemblies you need
  Fakes for. and generate the fakes, edit the .fakes file if you like,
  and build to generate the fake assemblies.

  From your Unit Test projects Just make sure that you have a reference
  to the Fakes runtime DLL: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
  12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll

  Then for each assembly that you have created Fakes for, add a
  reference to the corresponding DLL file in the
  Fakes.Prebuild\FakesAssemblies folder of your project. (This folder
  get created when you compile)

  To confirm You will need to add the reference by Browsing to the
  generated fake assembly..